# manually choose foreign key column mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

Let's say I have a bunch of MyISAM tables in a MySQL database. I know that if my tables are InnoDB MySQL Workbench will pick up the relationships between the tables automatically. But if my tables are MyISAM, is there a way that I can select which column to use as a foreign key in MySQL Workbench without MySQL Workbench adding a column in my table schema? For example, let's say I have these columns in a table called `users`:

```
id              PRIMARY KEY
username        VARCHAR (255)
password        VARCHAR (255)
email           VARCHAR (255)
user_type_id    INT
```

As you can see above, `user_type_id` would be a foreign key coming from a table called `user_types`. If I add a many-to-one relationship between my tables `users` and `user_types` in MySQL Workbench, a column `user_types_id` will be automatically added to the schema of my table `users` (because that's what MySQL Workbench considers as a foreign key usually). I don't want that to happen, I want to be able to tell MySQL Workbench to use the column `user_type_id` as my foreign key. Any way I can do that?

Thank you

**NOTE:** There is a Foreign Keys tab when I double click on a table on the model view in MySQL Workbench, but when I do so, I get the following text:

**Note: foreign keys can only be defined for certain storage engines (like InnoDB). The server accepts foreign key definitions for other storage engines but silently ignores them. Switch your table engine to one that supports foreign keys to allow adjustments here.**

Answer (score 2):

You could temporarily switch to InnoDB, define the relationship and switch back to MyISAM. The relationships will remain. BUT, they are of no real use except to document your intention.

If that's all you want then go ahead.

Btw: the FK tab page is only unavailable on Windows (for engines that don't support FKs), as we have seen many complaints from users that defined FKs for MyISAM, just to see no effect in their target DB. On Linux + OS X you can work on FKs regardless of the selected storage engine.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I believe you can do this from the Foreign Keys tab on the table itself.  If you double click a table from the model overview, on the bottom tabs there is a Foreign Key tab.  You can manually add in foreign keys however you choose from that dialog.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I tried that, when I click on the Foreign Keys that I cannot adjust anything, I just have a text saying that foreign keys can only be defined for certain storage engines like InnoDB. I'll update the post so someone else does not propose the same thing

Comment: Is there any reason you're using MyISAM vs InnoDB?  Just curious while I look around.

Comment: Cause the constraints are not defined directly in my tables (cause I'm using a framework, so I let the framework deal with the foreign key constraints on the tables)

Comment: I don't know much about MyISAM, but after poking around it seems like it doesn't support foreign key constraints:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655435/why-my-table-doesnt-support-foreign-keys

You could try switching to InnoDB though if that helps you out.  The SQL to do so is in the link.

Comment: I know MyISAM doesn't support foreign key constraints. So there's absolutely no way of doing what I'm trying to do without switching my tables to InnoDB?

Comment: Not that I've found thus far.