# Magento "General error: 1005 Can't create table"

Tags: mysql, magento, foreign-keys, magento-1.7, mysql-error-1005

I'm freaking out... working on a Magento site and all was well. Woke up this morning to continue work and the entire site (both front-end and admin) are throwing errors. The error log says:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:249:"Error in file: "/home1/ameridq4/public_html/pursuityourself/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/    install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'ameridq4_ecommerce-pursuit-magento.admin_assert' (errno: -1)";i:1;s:1168:"#0 /home1/ameridq4/public_html/pursuityourself/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home1/ameridq4/public_html/pursuityourself/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.1.0')
#2 /home1/ameridq4/public_html/pursuityourself/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.1.0')
#3 /home1/ameridq4/public_html/pursuityourself/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home1/ameridq4/public_html/pursuityourself/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home1/ameridq4/public_html/pursuityourself/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home1/ameridq4/public_html/pursuityourself/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home1/ameridq4/public_html/pursuityourself/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:10:"/magento/e";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I haven't done anything between last night when it was working fine and this morning... last thing I did yesterday was change the Default Store Name from "Default Store" to "Pursuit". Any ideas what happened and how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is a foreign key constraint and one of the tables is MyISAM. This storage engine does not support foreign key constraints. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655435/why-my-table-doesnt-support-foreign-keys)). The install file is that of the Admin module, so try to convert the `Mage_Admin` module tables  to InnoDB (execute in phpmyadmin or any other database client):

```
alter table admin_assert engine=innodb;
alter table admin_role engine=innodb;
alter table admin_rule engine=innodb;
alter table admin_user engine=innodb;
```

You may have to convert other tables to InnoDB as well, if they incorrectly have MyISAM storage engine. This [blog](http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-tutorials/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1005-cant-create-table/) has a script for that (back your database up before running this script). Every table in Magento core, except `catalogsearch_fulltext` (MyISAM) and temporary tables (MEMORY), is InnoDB.