# PHP My Admin Not Creating Relations

Tags: php, mysql

I am using xamp. 
I created a DB using SQL Yog, 
I opened my **localhost/phpmyadmin/** 
then selected the newly created database. 
I wanted to make relations among tables, for instance there are two tables,USER and USERSTATS, I want to create relation depending on USER_ID, which exists in both table. 
I selected create relation option, selected reference key from USERS table, then click on STATS table and selected foreign key, i got a prompt "Create relation", I clicked OK. 
Now it was to supposed to be creating relation, but it's not, just a small blank popup window opens in firefox, with link 
**localhost/phpmyadmin/pmd_general.php?db=MYDBNAME&server=1&token=d9d3ed2661d4cc1d0db47eca1ebee996**

But it is not creating the relation.

Please assist me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 2):

Have you created your tables with `InnoDB` ? `InnoDB` accepts creation of foreign keys

Comment: Mh.. same types for sure ? Or did you forget to put indexes on some keys ?

Answer (score 0):

`mysql` doesn't support the `foreign key` relations, though it accepts that keyword. That's probably the reason `phpMyAdmin` doesn't allow this.

If you can use `InnoDB` engine for your table, foreign keys are supported.

From an answer from stackoverflow for [why-my-table-doesnt-support-foreign-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655435/why-my-table-doesnt-support-foreign-keys)

`ALTER TABLE tableName ENGINE = InnoDB;`

Comment: I made relations in some other database, but this time it is creating problems. 
suggest some solution please.

Comment: @IrfanYounus yeah my answer includes individual suggestion only... I haven't mention that it alters all tables....that command works per table...if you think my answer helped solving your question...please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you go through the complete phpmyadmin installation steps? You have to create the phpmyadmin specific tables. Without them you will not be able to see relations or create them.

http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage

Answer (score 0):

you need to add an index to the field you want as foreign key. You can do it by going to the table and clicking "Index" or you can do it manually: "ALTER TABLE  `YourTable` ADD INDEX (  `YourField` )"