# Use of foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

In my interview, I was asked "what is the use of foreign key"?

My answer was:
"It is used to reference the primary key of next table that can be used to join the table".

And still, he said "you are not at the point". I tried google but still I can not find.

So what can be the answer?

Comment: The goal of a foreign key is to keep [referential integrity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)

Comment: I don't think a foreign key is required to reference a primary key. I believe it can reference a non-primary unique key as well.

Comment: @Pang: and MySQL extends it even further. It can reference any column or set of columns that are indexed. (It doesn't need to be unique index.) I can't fathom a case where I would use that extension.

Comment: I would have asked the interviewer for clarification, are you referring to a column in a table, or are you referring to a FOREIGN KEY *constraint*.?  When he said you're weren't on the point, he was meaning that you were correct, as far as a column in a table, we can refer to that generically as a "foreign key", though if we look at the table definition, we wouldn't see the keywords FOREIGN KEY until we got to the constraint definition. The constraint is a *rule* that is enforced by the database, and disallows some DML changes. (But foreign key constraints can be disabled and/or deferred.)

Answer (score 4):

A foreign key is a specific kind of constraint.
A constraint is a rule that restricts the values in a database.
Please follow this link to find detailed answer (It's for Oracle, not MySql, but the foreign key works in the same way in all databases):
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm

> **Use a constraint to define an integrity constraint--a rule that
>   restricts the values in a database**. Oracle Database lets you create
>   six types of constraints and lets you declare them in two ways.
>
> The six types of integrity constraint are described briefly here and
>   more fully in "Semantics":
>
> A NOT NULL constraint prohibits a database value from being null.
>
> A unique constraint prohibits multiple rows from having the same value
>   in the same column or combination of columns but allows some values to
>   be null.
>
> A primary key constraint combines a NOT NULL constraint and a unique
>   constraint in a single declaration. That is, it prohibits multiple
>   rows from having the same value in the same column or combination of
>   columns and prohibits values from being null.
>
> **A foreign key constraint requires values in one table to match values
>   in another table.**
>
> A check constraint requires a value in the database to comply with a
>   specified condition.
>
> A REF column by definition references an object in another object type
>   or in a relational table. A REF constraint lets you further describe
>   the relationship between the REF column and the object it references.

As you see from the definition - the foreign key is a constraint, that works in such a way, that it simply checks if a given value in a column of one table exists in a given column of another table.

Answer (score 2):

It is interesting that you tagged `mysql` here, because the default `MyISAM` engine in MySQL does not maintain referential integrity. In other words, it will actually allow you to create a foreign key, but it does not enforce anything (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655435/why-my-table-doesnt-support-foreign-keys)).

So if `Table2.ColumnB` had a foreign key to `Table1.ColumnA`, and you tried to add a value to `Table2.ColumnB` that did not exist in `Table1.ColumnA`, it would let you. It would not enforce the constraint for you. Other MySQL engines such as InnoDB however to support these constraints.

All of my early database work was in MySQL using a MyISAM engine. All foreign key constraints had to be enforced at the programming level since the database would not do it for me. This led to some problems when I started working with SQL Server because I was not properly setting up foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 1):

A ***FOREIGN KEY*** in one table points to a ***PRIMARY KEY*** in another table.
Suppose for example you have two tables, table one is having these columns, `pid`,`fname`,`lname` where `pid` is the primary key for the table one. Whereas, Table two is having these columns, `nid`, `value`, `pid`, here `nid` is primary key for table two and `pid` will act as foreign key for table two. This `pid` will act as link between two given tables. With the help of `pid` in table two, we can fetch the `value` data from table two for `fname` or `lname` of table one.

Comment: A foreign key does not have to point to a primary key. Though it tends to be best that it at least point to an indexed column, just for performance reasons.